# Passing NSDictionary value to an NSString

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstring, nsdictionary

I am wondering how can I pass a NSDictionary value to a variable.
say for instance my NSDictionary has 3 strings in it.. im wanting to know how I can apply the second string to a new NSString variable

Comment: say i have an NSDictionary with 3 NSStrings in it. I would like to get the second string from the NSDictionary and apply that to a NSString else where.

Comment: You could always look at the documentation, for simple questions like these. Xcode-> Help -> Documentation & API reference

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly what you want :

```
NSString *str = [theDict objectForKey:@"theKey"];
```

Comment: ahhh yep.. now I remember.. i could not think of what to search on google... I have the worst memory.

Comment: cool! I have just been going to the website. yea I should have used the documentation... did not think that one through.. its friday and I guess I'm kicking into holiday mode already :P

Answer (score 0):

well objects in NSDictionary aren't sorted so you can do `objectForKey:` or fast enumeration and select the 2nd value in that